# Dropbox SDK Java - write search query to get all files

Tags: java, dropbox

I'm working on a simple project to download all files with certain extensions. And I'm doing a search like this

```
public void findFile(String query){
        try{

            SearchV2Builder searchBuilder = client.files().searchV2Builder(query);

            List<String> fileExtensions = Arrays.asList(extensions);
            SearchOptions searchOptions = SearchOptions.newBuilder().withFileExtensions(fileExtensions).build();

            SearchV2Result searchResult = searchBuilder.withOptions(searchOptions).start();
            List<SearchMatchV2> searchMatches = searchResult.getMatches();

            System.out.println(searchMatches.size());
            for (SearchMatchV2 s: searchMatches){
                System.out.println(s.getMetadata());
            }

        }
        catch(DbxException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And i don't know how to write query to get all the files I tried `"*"` `""` and none of it worked. How to wrote correct query for that?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Searching-for-all-files-with-certain-extension-in-Java-API-and/td-p/502767 ]

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you have to include in your initial search string something you are specifically looking for - there does not seem to be the notion of a "wildcard" search in this string.

Also, there is no way to limit the query by date.

So for my usage, I always have directories that start with a known string ("p_"), and also include a YYYYMMDD string in them.

To return all directories, I query "p_" only.